How to add a template using {% include %} tag, by comparing which user is logged in, on django?
My asset_list html is like this
  
    <div class="right">
        <div class="search-container">
            <input type="text" id="searchInput" placeholder="Search by AssetName..." aria-label="Search">
            
                <button class="add-button" aria-label="Add Asset" id="addUserButton"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i> Add</button>
            
        </div>

login database is like this , with roles admin and user
class UserDetails(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=100)  # Ideally, this should be hashed
    role = models.CharField(max_length=45)

views for asset list
def asset_list(request):
    users = Asset_Table.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'asset_mng/asset_pro.html', {'users': users})

I have 2 roles Admin and User , when Admin is logged in, I want to show admin side bar and if user is logged in , show user sidebar.
{% include 'admin_sidebar.html'%} or {% include 'user_sidebar.html'%}

<div class="right">
        <div class="search-container">
            <input type="text" id="searchInput" placeholder="Search by AssetName..." aria-label="Search">
            
                <button class="add-button" aria-label="Add Asset" id="addUserButton"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i> Add</button>
            
        </div>


Use an if-clause to determine which role the logged-in user has:
{% if user.role == "admin" %}
    {% include 'admin_sidebar.html'%}
{% elif user.role == "user" %}
    {% include 'user_sidebar.html'%}
{% endif %}


Pass a variable from Django to the Jinja2 templating which tells you if you want admin or not and then use the conditional statements within Jinja2:
{% if admin %}
   {% include 'admin_sidebar.html'%}
{% else %}
   {% include 'user_sidebar.html'%}
{% endif %}

Then in the python:
return render(request, 'template.html', {'admin': True})

